# Substring string URL with several delimiters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a URL i need to substring it.In the below URL i need only document.doc part only
URL is

> localhost/abcd/abcs/document.doc

Here i tried

```
FilePath = r["FilePath"].ToString().Substring(0,1);
```

Comment: What is `r["FilePath"]` ?

Comment: What is the exact `c#` type ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

> Returns the file name and extension of the specified path string.

`System.IO.Path.GetFileName("localhost/abcd/abcs/document.doc") //document.doc`

Answer (score 1):

```
string url = "localhost/abcd/abcs/document.doc";
string part = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: I tried like this but ti says FileName Doesn't exist in the current context,thats Filename inside substring section FileName = r["FilePath"].ToString().Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1),

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var path = "localhost/abcd/abcs/document.doc";
var fileName = path.SubString(path.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: I tried like this but ti says FileName Doesn't exist in the current context,thats Filename inside substring section FileName = r["FilePath"].ToString().Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1),

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that your  r["FilePath"]   will always return string value and will not be null, then what you can do is assign this in a String variable. Then use the Substring function to get the value. For e.g.

```
    string FilePath = r["FilePath"].ToString();
    string filename = FilePath.SubString(FilePath.LastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Another option is as below

```
    string FilePath = r["FilePath"].ToString();
    string filename = FilePath.Split('/').ToList().Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(r["FilePath"].ToString()));
var filename = fi.Name;
var extension = fi.Extension;
```